# Send a "smaller" message or send a "shorter" message?

Tags: comparatives

I would like to know which comparative is correct when saying something like the following.

> The maximum size of a message is 150 words. Please send a [smaller|shorter] message.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello, borting. Logic would strongly suggest 'smaller', but 'shorter' is more idiomatic (even when smaller font-size may result in the message filling less of your screen). How many Google hits for "shorter message" and "smaller message" do you get? What do [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smaller+message%2Cshorter+message&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmaller%20message%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshorter%20message%3B%2Cc0) suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Small](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/small)** means "little in size", hence **smaller** means "littler in size".

**[Short](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/short)** means "having little length", hence **shorter** means "littler in length".

I would hence suggest that there are two logical options for you:

> 1. The maximum **size** of a message is 150 words. Please send a **smaller** message.
> 2. The maximum **length** of a message is 150 words. Please send a **shorter** message.

The second sounds much more natural to me. In my experience, messages have their *length* measured, not their *size*.